# own class with twocolumns activated in \ifdefined for KOMA and xelatex

Tags: koma-script, two-column, documentclass-writing, class-options

I want to do something like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465665/passing-command-line-arguments-to-latex-document.
For better explanation I'll show a minimal running example:
My `test.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2012/01/11 helper class]
\ifdefined\bastitwocolumns%
\LoadClass[DIV14,parskip=full,twocolumns,landscape]{scrartcl}%
\else
\LoadClass[DIV14,parskip=full]{scrartcl}%
\fi
```

and now my `test.tex`:

```
\listfiles
\def\bastitwocolumns{}
\documentclass{test}
%\ifdefined\bastitwocolumns\documentclass[DIV14,parskip=full,landscape,twocolumn]    {scrartcl}\else\documentclass[DIV14,parskip=full]{scrartcl}\fi
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\\
\blindtext
\par
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\\
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `xelatex` first the way the files are, results in a one column document a4. Activating line 4 and commenting out line 3 results in a two column (so sad portrait) a4 document.
The orientation problem might be ignored.
Can anyone explain, why I can not enable this two column setting in my class?

Okay, here is another minimal running example, which shows the problems more precise:

XeLaTeX-file:

```
\listfiles
\def\bastitwocolumns{}
\documentclass{ebelinguebung}
%\ifdefined\bastitwocolumns\documentclass[DIV14,parskip=full,landscape,twocolumn]    {scrartcl}\else\documentclass[DIV14,parskip=full]    {scrartcl}\fi\usepackage{beamerarticle}\usepackage{oldebelinguebung}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\\ \blindtext \par \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Class-file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ebelinguebung}[2012/01/11 helper class]
\ifdefined\bastitwocolumns%
\LoadClass[DIV14,parskip=full,landscape,twocolumn]{scrartcl}%
\else
\LoadClass[DIV14,parskip=full]{scrartcl}%
\fi
\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]    {german} 
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Style-file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{ebelinguebung}[2012/01/11]
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german} 
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

And now switching active lines 3 or 4 I get different results (one portrait, one landscape), which I like to understand.

Okay, after many tries I found one solution - which I do not really understand - but by the way:
In the logfile for twocolumn compilation with my class typearea shows (of course) the portrait sizes for the paper. But in the logfile for the package solution, typearea also tells

```
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `landscape'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `paper=landscape'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `paper=landscape' there
(typearea)             instead of `landscape', too.
```

First trying `paper=landscape` direct into the class options only removes those hint. Second trying to set `\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,twocolumn}%` (and removing the class options) within the if clause did, what I wanted.
Can anyone explain that?

Comment: If you add the commands I suggested, then the document is indeed printed in two column landscape format.

Comment: @egreg yes, you are right of course. But with my solution we do not need a further package loading... Thus, I prefer this a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `test.cls` is loaded, it follows the "true" part of the conditional, because line 2 of your document defines `\bastitwocolumns`, but of course it ignores the `twocolumns` option, because the right name is `twocolumn`.

Indeed, changing `twocolumns` into `twocolumn` in `test.cls` produces a two column document.

In order to get landscape format, you can modify `test.cls` in this way:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2012/01/11 helper class]
\ifdefined\bastitwocolumns
  \PassOptionsToPackage{landscape}{typearea}
  \LoadClass[DIV14,parskip=full,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
  \RequirePackage[pass]{geometry} % this ensures the correct paper orientation
\else
  \LoadClass[DIV14,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\fi
```

If you comment line 2 in `test.tex`, you'll get instead a one-column portrait document.

Comment: Hi egreg, thanks. 2columns are now working fine. Can you explain, why geometry is needed in this setting? Using the "package"-version it will work.  
Further the "true" part should always be used here to be tested... it is an implementation following the cited article.

Comment: @BastianEbeling I tried without it, but didn't succeed in persuading `scrartcl` to produce a landscape document. I *know* that `geometry` issues the right commands in order to have the correct paper format; the `pass` option will avoid any modification of the parameters.

Comment: Sorry @egreg! In my more complicated example, which I derived the minexmpl. from, some other things occur. At the moment it seems, as if hyperref helps - but only in a package. Maybe I post another minexmpl. soon. Thx!